# Valid to specify width for form tag - either inline or through css?

Tags: html, css, forms

I just need to know if we can specify with for form tag or we need to put it in a container and give width to that parent element of form tag??

Which approach is valid??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, a form element behaves a lot like a div in most situations, and so will accept a width, but usually this is just an implied 'auto'.

According to the Default stylesheet ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html ), form naturally is applied display:block, which leads me to believe you can treat it just like any other block element.

Comment: more accurately, form behaves like width:auto, not width:100%